# woeusb insists on unmounting the source image

Tags: woeusb

I'm running Kubuntu 18.04 and I'm trying to use **woeusb** to create a boot memory stick for  SuSE Leap.  I've set the source to an ISO file for SuSE Leap and the target to /dev/sdb.  I've unmounted /dev/sdb1, but I still get a puzzling error message:**Source media is currently mounted, unmount the partition then try again**. This is particularly mysterious because the source *should* be mounted.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Find the USB device you want to use, in my case it was `/dev/sda1` with `sudo lsblk`.

Then simply unmount it with `sudo umount /dev/sda1` and try again in WoeUSB

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it's necessary to explicitly unmount the source file. I've never before had to unmount an ordinary file, or at least a file that's not explicitly mounted to a device.  I didn't even know that it's possible, but apparently it is.

Comment: You can **loop mount** some kinds of files (iso files and other image files, that contain file systems). See for example [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/iso2usb/diy). Example `sudo mount -o loop file.iso /mnt/` After loop mouning you can extract the content of the iso file.

Answer (score 0):

```
# https://github.com/WoeUSB/WoeUSB/releases

Release='https://github.com/WoeUSB/WoeUSB/releases/download/v5.2.4/woeusb-5.2.4.bash'

Woeusb = `basename $Release`

Iso="$windows_iso_address"

cd Downloads && \
mkdir Woeusb && \
cd Woeusb && \
wget "$Release" && \
sudo su

chmod +x "$Woeusb"


Windows = 'mnt/Windows'
mkdir "$Windows"

mount -o loop "$Iso" $Windows

Loopdevice = `df -h | grep $Windows`

File_system='NTFS'
Target_file_system="--target-filesystem $File-system"
Target="$Target_file_system"

bash $Woeusb --target-filesystem $Target \
             --device "$Loopdevice" \
             /dev/sd_
```

Comment: Could you please add a few explanatory notes to your answer? Without such notes your answer has already been flagged by the Community as 'Not an Answer'...

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the line where it is terminating the program by modifying the /usr/bin/woeusb with vim by Searching for the error "Source media**" delete the line below it saying "exit 1". After that running the woeusb still show the error but installation will not be terminated.